# Factory unlock iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm in India.

I bought an iPhone 4 some time back. The vendor informed me that it is a factory unlocked version (iPhone 4 is officially not launched in India yet).

So, my questions are

1. Is there a way to find out whether it is a genuinely factory unlocked version?
2. If it's indeed a factory unlocked version, will I be able to update to the latest iOS version without getting it locked?
3. Since it is either a Canada/UK version, will updating the iOS in India create any problem (auto IP detection, time zone blah blah)?

I tried installing an `.ipa` file directly and it didnt work. What I'm guessing through that is that my iPhone is not a jailbroken one. I read somewhere that to unlock an iPhone, one needs to jailbreak it first. That concludes, it is indeed a factory unlock version since any GSM SIM works.

Do you think my logic is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is not correct. For a while, there were people offering unlocking services for around US$170 who are believed to have bribed an employee of Apple or a mobile phone operator to unlock phones using the official channels, and those phones also didn't need to be jailbroken. There's no way I know of to distinguish one of those phones from a factory unlocked one.

Assuming it is a genuine factory unlock, there should be no problems -- I have a UK factory unlocked iPhone 4 and have upgraded the OS several times, though I've never tried to do so in another country.

Comment: @ptamzz That hack (gevey) Mike mentioned [should be prove](http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2011/03/27/musclenerd-confirms-the-gevey-sim-iphone-4-unlock-is-illegal/) there might **never** be some way to know for sure if an iPhone was genuinely factory unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to find out whether it
>   is a genuinely factory unlocked
>   version?

Yes. Remove the SIM. Insert a SIM from a different network. If the phone works, it is unlocked.

To be sure that it's *factory unlocked*, you can restore to factory settings and repeat the above test.

> If it's indeed a factory unlocked
>   version, will I be able to update to
>   the latest iOS version without getting
>   it locked?

Yes.

> Since it is either a Canada/UK
>   version, will updating the iOS in
>   India create any problem (auto IP
>   detection, time zone blah blah)?

No.

> I read somewhere that to unlock an
>   iPhone, one needs to jailbreak it
>   first.

This is basically true. But factory unlocked phones don't need to be unlocked, so they don't need to be jailbroken.

Comment: I guess you are not clear about the first part of my Question. A *Factory Unlocked* and an *third party Unlocked* iPhone are different. Both works with any SIM but  Factory Unlocked ones are apple verified. I was asking if it's a *Factory* unlocked or just a third party *unlocked* one.

Answer (score 1):

Jailbroken iPhonea get relocked when you update the software, but factory unlocked iPhones remain unlocked if you update the software.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use online unlock services to unlock your device. They are cheap & permanent and your warranty will still remain valid.